# Error in subversion installation on ubuntu server "Unable to locate package"

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to install subversion on ubuntu 12.04 server. when i execute command
"sudo apt-get install subversion libapache2-svn" I am getting error as

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done

E: Unable to locate package subversion

E: Unable to locate package libapache2-svn

I googled it and tried the suggested solution "apt-get update" but it didn't work.
Could anyone provide me solution?

Answer (score 2):

Depends what's in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` - you may well need to uncomment some of the repositories listed in there. The only ones I have commented out are the ones for Canonical's 'partner' and 'extras' repositories and an `apt-cache search subversion` or `apt-cache search libapache2-svn` find the respective packages.

If you uncomment any repositories in sources.list don't forget to run `sudo apt-get update` before searching or attempting to install.

Comment: in my system also only these two repos are commented. I checked by removing them also,but still facing the same problem.

Comment: What happens when you try `apt-get update`, how doesn't it work?

Comment: when i try apt-get update i get below errors:



W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/svn18/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden

W: Failed to fetch http://opensource.wandisco.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/svn18/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.    @orbey

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing the "http://" with "ftp://" in my /etc/apt/sources.list. 
I don't know whether its correct way but for a moment it resolved my issue.